# Magento product list page - group products by color attribute

Tags: php, magento

I need a help with magento. There are two attributes for creating configurable products, size and color. On the category page where products are listed, I want to display only different colors of products not sizes. I've to group products by color.

I.e. if there is a shirt with colors red, blue, gray, black and for each color there are a sizes M, L, XL (there are 12 simple products), I need to display only 4 products grouped by color.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe your approach for configurable products is wrong - IMHO it should be the whole COLOR as a configurable and then SIZES as SIMPLES so in this case you would have 4 configurables and 3 simples for each ex. SHIRT-RED-M, SHIRT-RED-L, SHIRT-RED-XL as the SKU.

But that's just a suggestion..

As for your original problem - isn't it just this:

```
$collection =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->groupByAttribute('color');
```

?

Comment: Thanks man, honestly I didn't think in that way, maybe you are right and thanks for suggestion. I've already tried this snippet of code earlier but getting an error unknown column color even in the case I put addAttributeToSelect('color')

Comment: I have quite a similar problem but I need to have the possibility to choose different color and size while in the product view. If I create different configurable products for colors, I will not be able to change the color, will I ?

Comment: My suggested approach doesn't cover all of the cases but the grouping should be able to achieve in both ways. What particularly do U want to do and what effect do you have now?